# MYSQL Trigger To Populate New Table

Tags: mysql

Hey all so I have created a table named products that looks like so:

```
`CREATE TABLE products
(
Prod_ID int(10),
Prod_name varchar(20),
Prod_qty varchar(20),
Prod_price int(20)
);`
```

Product_log table is nearly identical to another table called products:

```
`CREATE TABLE product_log
(
Prod_ID int(10),
Prod_name varchar(20),
Action_Date date,
Updated_by varchar(30),
Action varchar(30)
);`
```

Next I have created a trigger called products_after_insert which should insert data into the product_log table after a row in products is inserted.
The requirement for after insert trigger is that action date should be inserted in the product_log table and the user name should be inserted like who inserted the data ex: data operator,
 and on last the action should be inserted in the product_log table automatically like action here is insertion.
here is my trigger:

```
`DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER products_after_insert
AFTER INSERT 
ON products 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DECLARE data_operator int(10);
DECLARE action_per varchar(200);
SET data_operator = 1;
SET action_per = 'INSERTION';
IF data_operator=1 THEN
INSERT INTO product_log(prod_id,prod_name,Action_date,Updated_by,Action)
VALUES(NEW.prod_id,NEW.prod_name,SYSDATE(),'data_operator','action_per');
END IF;
END; 
//DELIMITER;`
```

Now, I assume I am constructing my trigger incorrectly because it appears to not be working.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There's at least this you are doing wrong :

```
VALUES(NEW.prod_id,NEW.prod_name,SYSDATE(),'data_operator','action_per');
```

You have properly defined the variables `data_operator` and `action_per` previously:

```
SET data_operator = 1;
SET action_per = 'INSERTION';
```

But in your INSERT instruction you surrounded them with quotes, which turned them into strings. Your instruction should be :

```
VALUES(NEW.prod_id,NEW.prod_name,SYSDATE(),data_operator,action_per);
```